# Connecting to a 192.* VPN network from 10.* network

Tags: networking, vpn

Firstly, I would like to apologise for my rather poor grasp of networking.

My home network is a 10.* network (my ISP for some reason mandates this).

I want to connect to a VPN at my workplace which is a 192.168.1.* network.

Connection to VPN succeeds. On printing ipconfig, I get:

```
  Windows IP Configuration


  PPP adapter VizVPN:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.240
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Buttons
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64da:dd21:9582:3f4c%11
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.4
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1

  Tunnel adapter isatap.Buttons:

  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Buttons

  Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
  IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:34b7:e4fd:95cc:7f05
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::34b7:e4fd:95cc:7f05%12
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

  Tunnel adapter isatap.{223C1CE3-3E17-44FE-B356-57E96CC14047}:

  Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

However, while I am able to ping 192.168.1.240 assigned to me on the VPN network, I am unable to ping any other computers on that network. Needless to say, I cannot access files on any machines in the remote network either.

I am using PPTP for VPN. I have also unchecked the box that says: "Use default gateway on remote network"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall status? Can you ping other machines on the different subnet?

Comment: Yes, I tried disabling firewall completely, but no luck. I cannot ping any machines on the VPN subnet.

Comment: Not sure why you're pinging the IP assigned to you by the VPN server... if you were trying to test the ping then pinging the VPN server's address would prove connectivity. Additionally, although your VPN server is dishing out 192.168.1.x addresses, what are your remote network IP addresses? You may find that the remote computer IPs are within your 10. range and conflicting with YOUR home network... a number of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect to Remote Server and getting the IP assigned then the role of client is finished. Now the packets should be routed properly at the server end. So, if you are not able to ping any other machine in the remote network then it means the PPTP server is not creating proper route for
 flowing the packet inside the network.

You need to talk to the Network administrator , He can definitely figure this out at his end.

:-)

Comment: Since you @Randhir are my server administrator, I am not going to upvote this answer, since it feels like cheating to award answer points to someone within the company itself. Also, thanks for solving the actual issue.